# Как зафиксировать курсор мыши?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня. Есть абсолютно спозиционированный элемент, который по mouse up получает данные pageX и записывает их в свойство left, тем самым перемещая элемент по горизонтали. движение элемента задано в определенных рамках, от 0 до 200px. Проблема в том, что движение элемента останавливается на 200px, а сам курсор можно перемещать дальше, как по вертикали, так и по горизонтали, подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли по событию mouse up привязать курсор к точке, где оно произошло, запретить движение курсора по вертикали и ограничить движение по горизонтали.
Спасибо.

Comment: воздействовать на курсор через js невозможно. вместо этого просто проверяй достигнутый предел. Если достигнут, то приравнивай его к максимальному. `if (currentX >= maxX) { currentX = maxX; }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну вообще [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API), хотя для случая автора это наверно не очень подходит

Comment: @andreymal это поможет запретить движение курсора по вертикали и ограничить движение по горизонтали?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это поможет скрыть настоящий курсор и нарисовать фейковый в нужной позиции :D Но, повторюсь, автору вряд ли подойдёт)

Comment: @andreymal нюююю, я та думал тама и правдашта космас)

Comment: Сейчас бы через браузерный код влиять на системный ... сборище футуристов....